# Spring boot consider defining a bean of type, component scan not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to follow the below tutorial:

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

My pom is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nuril.work</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootHiberate</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

When I run the Application class as shown:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    SoccerService soccerService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        soccerService.addBarcelonaPlayer("Xavi Hernandez", "Midfielder", 6);
        List<String> players = soccerService.getAllTeamPlayers(1);
        for(String player : players)
        {
            System.out.println("Introducing Barca player => " + player);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the below error:

```
Description:

Field playerRepository in com.nuril.work.service.SoccerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.nuril.work.repository.PlayerRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.nuril.work.repository.PlayerRepository' in your configuration.
```

I looked at other answers and they suggested to add @ComponentScan annotation.

I added the following

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.nuril.work.repository") 
@ComponentScan("com.nuril.work.service")
```

However I am still getting the same error, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: You might be missing @Component annotation on PlayerRepository

Comment: Why have you excluded `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` ?

Comment: becuase it got rid of the error: Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: That's because you haven't defined your datasource.

Comment: Yes, my file was called app.properties instead of application.properties, after changing the filename I no longer get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.nuril.work.repository")` onto `Application` class.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html

Also, check if your repositories have `@Repository` annotation.